# How can I modify Alpaca Radiobutton Serialization

Tags: alpacajs

I need to have my radio buttons output their json like:
{
answered:true
}

Current Schema:

```
"type" : "object",
               "properties":{
                    "product":{
                      "name" : "Product XYZ Truck"
                    },
                    "question-154":{
                        "required": true,
                        "type":"string",
                        "enum": ["Q/RED", "Q/GREEN", "Q/BLUE", "Q/WHITE", "Q/BLACK"]
                    },
```

Current Options:

```
"fields": {
                "question-154": {
                    "title":"Question-154",
                    "type": "radio",
                    "label": "Favorite Color",
                    "helper": "Pick your favorite color",
                    "optionLabels": {
                        "Q/RED": "Red",
                        "Q/GREEN": "Green",
                        "Q/BLUE": "Blue",
                        "Q/WHITE": "White",
                        "Q/BLACK": "Black"
                    }
                },
                "question-182": {
                    "title":"Question-182",
                    "type": "radio",
                    "label": "Engine",
                    "helper": "Pick your preferred engine",
                    "optionLabels": {
                        "Q1/h1": "Hybrid",
                        "Q1/e2": "Electric",
                        "Q1/d1": "Diesel",
                        "Q1/g1": "Gas"
                    }
                }
```

Right now it is giving me

{"question-154" : "Q/RED"}

However, I actually need it to be represented as:

{"Q/RED":"true"}

How can I use or modify Alpaca to serialize in that manner?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the result for example in a submit button:

```
"options": {
    "form": {
        "attributes": {
            "action": "http://httpbin.org/post",
            "method": "post"
        },
        "buttons": {
            "submit": {
                "click": function() {
```

The method this.getValue() is the javascript Object with the data of the form. You can manipulate it and for example send it to the server.

You can see for example values in the log with:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.getValue()));
```